# Request pictures from instagram tags does not return all of them

Tags: javascript, instagram

I have some items, every item has some tags, and I am trying to do an instagram request for each one of this tags and display the pictures related to all the tags.

It seems it is working, but I only can see the pictures of the second tag (if the item has more than one tag).

I'm pretty sure that the problem is the line:

```
target.empty();
```

that is not placed in the correct place, but I tryed to change its place and I get no pictures, all the pictures of all the items, etc...

https://jsfiddle.net/re7vkbwq/37/

The instagram request is done every time I display  the information of an item, all of the items shares the same modal to display its information with angular and an ng-repeat.

I updated the fiddle with the correct json request, before this it was wrong ad I writed an array.

I tryed to call the target.empty() to the very beginning, but it returns me an empty target at the end. It should work, I don't get why is not working like this:

```
instagramTags = function(tags){
  target.empty();
  tags.forEach(function(tag) {
    grabImages(tag.name, 3, access_parameters);
  });
};
```

I tried to put it after the forEach even though it seems no sense and it returns some images of one of the tags:

```
instagramTags = function(tags){
      tags.forEach(function(tag) {
        grabImages(tag.name, 3, access_parameters);
      });
    target.empty();
    };
```

Comment: do you want to grap all the images there are or a certain ammount?

Comment: I only want to grab a limited number of images that I hardcode (in the example 3 but it could be more or less) from each one of the tags. If for example there are three tags, I need 3 pictures of each tag, a total of 9 pictures. But actually I only get 3 pictures, not 9.

Comment: I see what you mean, i had a look, changed the way you loop by using a for loop and i saw you where trying to get the name of the tags by object, i made you loop through the array and then used each of them and thus outputting 3, there is the update on your code - http://jsfiddle.net/re7vkbwq/24/

Comment: I wrote the input wrong when I tryed to change the code, the actual json input is [ { name: "cognitive" }, { name: "something" } ]

Comment: Just comment out  `target.empty()` and your new code works.  The current code clears the input on each run of the function.

Comment: I need to empty the target before adding images to not have the previous images when I call it again, but if I put it here: instagramTags = function(tags){ target.empty();
      tags.forEach(function(tag) {
        grabImages(tag.name, 3, access_parameters);
      });
    }; then the target is empty after retrieving the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check net in the console, in your fiddle, you'll see that the tag is not defined in the Instagram API request.  This seems to work:

Code below updated to reflect corrected question and OP's comments.

```
         var access_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
access_parameters = {
    access_token: access_token
};

instagramTags = function(tags){
  $('.pictures').empty();
  tags.forEach(function(tag) {
    grabImages(tag.name, 3, access_parameters);
  });
};

function grabImages(tag, count, access_parameters) {
  var instagramUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tag + '/media/recent?callback=?&count=' + count;
  $.getJSON(instagramUrl, access_parameters, onDataLoaded);
}

function onDataLoaded(instagram_data) {
  var target = $(".pictures");
  //console.log(instagram_data);
  if (instagram_data.meta.code == 200) {
      var photos = instagram_data.data;
      //console.log(photos);
      if (photos.length > 0) {
          //target.empty();
          for (var key in photos) {
              var photo = photos[key];
              target.append('<a href="' + photo.link + '"><img class="thumbnail" src="' + photo.images.thumbnail.url + '"></a>')
          }
      } else {
          target.html("nothing found");
      }
  } else {
      var error = instagram_data.meta.error_message;
      target.html(error);
  }
}

instagramTags([
  {
    name: "ruby"
  },
  {
    name: "cry"
  },
  {
    name: "fun"
  }
]);
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/re7vkbwq/42/)

Comment: but if I delete the instagramTags = function(tags){ ... } then I can't do requests from the items, this is the way I am requesting the images.

Comment: Not sure I follow - the code above (and in the fiddle) loops through each tag, makes a request to Instagram and displays the 3 images.

Comment: I had a mistake when doing the fiddle, the tags are in json and not in an array. I'm trying to create a right json chain and update the code. Sorry

Comment: The input json is this: [ { name: "cognitive" }, { name: "something" } , {name:"fitness"}]

Comment: So is my function instagramTags wrong? when I do debugger it seems to work. And this is the way I retrieve the images from the web. And I need to target.empty(); because if I don`t the next time I retrieve pictures it is showed the previous ones and the new ones

Comment: I mean that if I do var tags =  [ { name: "metallica" }, { name: "anthrax" } , {name:"megadeth"}]; and later I do var tags =  [ { name: "slayer" }, { name: "dave mustaine" } , {name:"ozzy"}]; they will be displayed the 9 first images and the 9 second images at the same time, as a result I will have 18 images instead of 9. And if I call it again...

Comment: You need to clear the `.pictures` div as part of the function that loads the new tags, not inside the function that displays the images.

Comment: I updated the last part of the question, I tried it in the first function in the begining and there are no images at the end...

Comment: Instead of `target.empty();`,  use `$('.pictures').empty();` - `target` has not been defined in the first function.  Updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/re7vkbwq/42/)

Comment: $('.pictures').empty(); YEAH!!! now you solved all my problem. I don't know why I didn' realised it. Thank You!!